# SendGrid API returning 400 when I add more JSON properties

Tags: c#, azure-functions, sendgrid

I'm trying to use the SendGrid API to create and schedule a Single Send email to a contact list when my Azure Functions endpoint is called. Here is the minimum amount of information that I can create the single send with and have it work with a 200 response.

```
private static SendGridClient _client = new SendGridClient(
        Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SendGridApiKey")
    );

...


var data = new {
            name    = "Title",
            send_to = new {
                list_ids = new [] {
                    $"{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SendGridMailingId")}",
                }
            },
            email_config = new {
                design_id = $"{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SendGridDesignId")}",
            }
        };

        var singleSendResp = await _client.RequestAsync(
            method: SendGridClient.Method.POST,
            urlPath: "marketing/singlesends",
            requestBody: JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data)
        );
        return singleSendResp;
```

The problem is that I'd like to include the `send_at: "now"`, `suppression_group_id`, and `sender_id`, but if I include any of them (as well as all of them), I get this response:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "field": "",
            "message": "json could not be unmarshalled"
        }
    ]
}
```

I've tried all combinations of the above, and have even tried including all the properties that can't be `null` (minus the `subject`, `html_content`, etc since I have `design_id`.

I'm using the 9.28.1 SendGrid NuGet package, which should correspond to SendGrid's v3 API. I'm doing my testing locally with Postman. I am using the free version of the API, if that matters.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

EDIT: Here would be my ideal object to send, with extra fields.

```
var data = new {
            name    = "Title",
            send_at = "now",
            send_to = new {
                list_ids = new [] {
                    Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SendGridMailingId")
                }
            },
            email_config = new {
                design_id = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SendGridDesignId"),
                sender_id = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SendGridSenderId"),
                suppression_group_id = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SendGridSuppressionId")
            }
        };
```

Comment: Can you show us the structure of your payload in a string format WITH the additional fields that aren't working?

Comment: I finally figured out the issue, and it's a dumb mistake (as always).
`sender_id` and `suppression_group_id` are supposed to be integers, but I was just sending the string. Wrapping the values in an `int.Parse()` works. Also, even though `send_at` is supposed to be allowed a value of `"now"`, it only works with the date string.

Comment: @SeanPoston, I'll try to replicate the issue with the "now" string and report it to SendGrid.
If you could, can you answer your own question and mark it as solved?

Comment: Apparently `"now"` isn't allowed for `send_at` on the create endpoint, but it is allowed on the [schedule API](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/single-sends/schedule-single-send). Based on my testing specifying the `send_at` property during create doesn't actually send the email, just sets the field, you still have to schedule it using the API or UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out the issue, and it's a dumb mistake (as always). sender_id and suppression_group_id are supposed to be integers, but I was just sending the string. Wrapping the values in an int.Parse() works.

Also, even though send_at is supposed to be allowed a value of "now", it only works with the date string. For this, I included the following to format the string

```
string scheduleDate = DateTime.Now
    .ToUniversalTime()
    .AddMinutes(5)
    .ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");
```